# Deleting/adding self referring "friend" using Entity Framework 4.1 - DB First approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I got User model generated by ET 4.1 - I made DB first:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        this.My_requests = new HashSet<User>();
        this.Requests = new HashSet<User>();
        this.FriendLeft = new HashSet<User>();
        this.FriendRight = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string House_number { get; set; }
    public string Apartment_number { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string Zip_code { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> My_requests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Requests { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FriendLeft { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FriendRight { get; set; }
}
```

Every 'User' can invite other 'User' to become his friend. So when someone invite you, he appear in 'Request', when you invite someone he appear in 'My_requests'. That data is strored in 'Friend_requests' table wchich look like:

ProposerId(col1)  RecipientId(col2)

and both columns are in relationship with User table by UserId - it's many to many.

My problem is to delete row from 'Friend_request', because EF doesn't give me context for that table, instead it generated model shown before...

I tried something like that:

```
User User2 = GetUserInfo(UserId2);
context.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(UserId1)).SingleOrDefault().Requests.Remove(User2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But thats of course wrong, it gave me an error:

> "Can't update EntitySet „Friends_Request”, because it has element DefiningQuery, and in element  there is no element , wchich can handle this operation."

And my questions are:
How I can delete and how to add rows to table 'Friend_Requests'?

**EDIT:**

Table relations:
[image]

And in model generated by ET it's:
My_requests -> when User is Proposer
Requests -> when User is Recipient

Still the problem is how to add new "Friend requests" and how to delete them?

Comment: Are `ProposerId` and `RecipientId` in your `Friend_requests` table both primary keys?

Comment: Nope, they are just FK from User table. Both are in relationship with User table by UserId (2 keys). I can't make them both PK if they are in relation with same column in User... I want to make some like "transiton table" but with 2 tables not 3, because both columns are related to same table :/ If need i can draw some database schema :)

Comment: But it's probably the reason for your exception that the columns are not primary keys. I don't understand your argument why you can't make them PKs. The composite primary key would just forbid that *the same pair* of `ProposerId` and `RecipientId` can occur more than once (which makes sense in your model and every many-to-many relationship, no matter if self-referencing or not).

Comment: Shame on me... I was sure i set primary keys, but when i was trying to sole this problem so much time (editing, deleting, recreating tables) i forgot to make them again. Now with composite key on both columns and with 2 relationships both on User table col Id, i can easly add/remove elements like on normal List. Thanks much Slauma - larning on own mistakes are the best ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course Slauma as a experienced EF user, was right from the beginning. Without keys on Friends table it won't work. Add/remove elements now works normally as i write before. Just use like normal List. Learn on your own mistakes :)

Comment: Nice one @Gret Arnold